# Stored procedure to search Table based on multiple values from dropdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three down with different values such as

Category One dropdown

Category Two dropdown

Year dropdown

I Have to search Product table based on dropdown values it should filter search based on any one of the dropdown or all of the dropdown selected values.

Let us say i have following fields in Product Table

```
ProductID
ProductName
ProductCatOne
ProductCatTwo
Description
Image
....
....
```

How is the most efficient way to write a store procedure so that i cant handle any of the three value selected. I want to avoid two many if statements in store procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchProduct]
    @ProductID int,
    @ProductCatOne int,
   @ProductCatTwo int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

If @ProductID > 0 THEN

END IF 


END
```

STORED PROCEDURE FOR MS SQL SERVER

I am not sure how to create dynamic query inside SP fr this search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). I recommend you to read this excellent article by Erland Sommarskog. He explains several ways to do it and why `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is needed if you don't use dynamic SQL as in the example below.

Few notes.

It is [bad practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx) to name your stored procedures with the prefix `sp_`.

I prefer to pass `NULL` value instead of `0` to indicate that this parameter should be ignored. `0` value can be a valid value for search.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchProduct]
    @ProductID int,
    @ProductCatOne int,
    @ProductCatTwo int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM Products
    WHERE
        (ID = @ProductID OR @ProductID IS NULL)
        AND (ProductCatOne = @ProductCatOne OR @ProductCatOne IS NULL)
        AND (ProductCatTwo = @ProductCatTwo OR @ProductCatTwo IS NULL)
    OPTION(RECOMPILE);

END
```

This code assumes that columns `ID`, `ProductCatOne`, `ProductCatTwo` can't have NULLs.

Comment: I am exactly looking for this.. otherwise I will end up doing many if conditions. is `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`  available in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Yes, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` (as it is intended to be) is available starting from SQL Server 2008. Make sure that you've applied service packs. See the Erland's article for details.

Comment: All my values are `Int` Type but i can pass Null value for non selected dropdown

Comment: @Learning, exactly. If the user didn't choose anything in the, say, CategoryOne drop-down, then you want to ignore this parameter. To make the query ignore this parameter you pass `NULL` for it in the stored procedure.

Comment: Agree with you 100%. This is best way to handle thsi kind of search otherwise i had to write too many IF statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchProduct]
    @ProductID int,
    @ProductCatOne int,
   @ProductCatTwo int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @ProductID =''
    SET @ProductID=NULL

    IF @ProductCatOne =''
    SET @ProductCatOne=NULL

    IF @ProductCatTwo =''
    SET @ProductCatTwo=NULL

    SELECT * 
    FROM Product
    WHERE ID = COALESCE (@ProductID,ID) 
          AND  ProductCatOne =COALESCE (@ProductID,ProductCatOne ) 
          AND  ProductCatTwo=COALESCE (@ProductID,ProductCatTwo) 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchProduct]
    @ProductID int,
    @ProductName int,
    @ProductCatOne int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM Products
    WHERE
    (Case When @ProductID <> 'ALL' Then ProductID Else @ProductID End ) in(@ProductID) And
    (Case When @ProductName <> 'ALL' Then ProductName Else @ProductName End ) in(@ProductName) And
    (Case When @ProductCatOne <> 'ALL' Then ProductCatOne Else @ProductCatOne End ) in(@ProductCatOne)


END
```